# Is there a way to modify or write a new version of CSTYLE_COMMENT in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: c, code-generation, enterprise-architect

I am trying to find a way of creating a custom function macro in Enterprise Architect to "override" the built-in `CSTYLE_COMMENT` macro with a custom version of it that creates comments differently to use for operation headers when generating code.

EA's built-in `CSTYLE_COMMENT` generates comments like this:

```
/**
* Name: OperationA
* Inputs: int int
* Outputs: -
* Description: It doesn't do stuff
*/
```

I want to create some custom template that generates comments like this:

```
/***********************************
* Name: OperationA
* Inputs: int int
* Outputs: -
* Description: It doesn't do stuff
***********************************/
```

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing so? My efforts on finding any detailed guide on syntax online have been futile. Even though SparX systems has the exact search term that I looked for here:
https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/codetemplatesyntax.html
there is no useful information on how to do what I want.

Comment: I don't use that scrappy macro language but export such stuff with the API.  I don't think you can alter it except for digging in those macros. But their basics can't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of doing this but I am not sure it is the best and it does not work well with reverse engineering and synchronization of the model. I could not find how to write my own macro as there is literally no documentation anywhere I looked.

This is how I did it:
Instead of

```
%CSTYLE_COMMENT($wrapLen)%
```

I wrote

```
/***************************************\n
%WRAP_COMMENT(opNotes,$wrapLen, "", "*")%
\n***************************************/
```

It worked exactly as I intended it to.

**EDIT:** I found what was missing to be able to correctly reverse engineer this commenting format. In EA 14, I navigated to START->Preferences->Source Code Engineering and I unchecked the option "Remove hard breaks from comments on import". This made the reverse engineering work correctly and update comments in the Element Notes field without losing their layout.

Comment: You can't make your own macros, or edit existing ones. These are hardcoded in EA.